# extract number from a text file into variable using list

Tags: python, list

I've a .text file with text

> .numvar 5

I want to extract this 5 into a separate variable and use.
I've used list to extract value but, I cannot manipulate the variable.

```
    if ".numvars" in line:
    splitter=re.compile(r'\d+')
    numvars=splitter.findall(line)
    numvars=map(int, numvars)
```

how to store the 5 in separate variable.

Comment: `if ".numvars" in line:` should be `if ".numvar" in line:` based on your file with text example

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import re

with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if ".numvar" in line:
            splitter = re.compile(r'\d+')
            numvars = splitter.findall(line)
            my_numbers = [int(n) for n in numvars]
            my_number = my_numbers[0]
            print(my_number)
```